# I've been given a quest to collect an item from Lydia, but she is dead.  How do I complete the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Long ago in my Skyrim characters growth, Lydia was my companion, and then I entered a dungeon and it was dark, and I missed with my sword and Lydia died, but I didn't realise for sometime afterward that she wasn't with me, so I had to go back and search, and she was dead in a dark part of a tunnel, so it was a long way back to be able to go to previous save, so I just let it be.

Sometime later when I got married, she turned up at my wedding dead so she's actually dead in laying on the floor just inside the door of the Temple in Riften.

I have been issued a quest from someone in the mages college to go collect an item from her.

Is there a way to complete or cancel the quest?  I have the PS3 version, so console solutions will not work.

Comment: While this isn't a solution, the quest you've been given sounds like a Radiant quest, so it's just randomly generated and not story-related. If it's broken, you can still continue.

Comment: Wow, what a wingman! Your best man goes into a dark dungeon to retrieve the body of your dead ex-girlfriend and brings her to your wedding... hilarious wedding joke! That's what you get when all your friends are necromancers...

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41004/1561), as long as it's not a unique item you might be able to get away with the following:

- Find the item elsewhere
- Go to Lydia's body, "store" the item and then close the inventory
- Retrieve the item from her body.

Comment: will try this tonight

Comment: Did this work?   If so, what was the item?   I'm in the same fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [“revive” her](http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/m98sv/revive_lydia/c2zsa7v):

> If you're on the PC, you can use the console to "revive her" (or clone her if you please I imagine) by typing
>
> ```
> player.placeatme 000a2c8e
> ```
>
> (One opens the console with the ~ key, enter the command and press enter/return) Her corpse disappeared for me, and this worked.

(When I tried this, her corpse didn't disappear, but the Lydia that appeared didn't seem to mind.)

Comment: can't use console note i said PS3

Comment: Hmm, I must have overlooked that.

Comment: no biggie maybe in the future a console might be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you have not Progressed much sense she died, go back to a save where she was still alive. If not then as Thaumajig said  that it is not story related and pretty much standing quest the computer made up for you just to give you somthing to do, so you can keep on going with no worrys

Comment: can't this was long ago (about level 20) that she died, i'm now level 50