# Where can I find a Forsworn Briar Heart?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repairing the white phial quest broken?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41003/repairing-the-white-phial-quest-broken)

I'm level 75 at Skyrim, with nearly all skills at 100, all the side quest of guild are done.

The quest from the Alchemy seller in Windhelm, he's asking for a Forsworn Briar Heart, I killed the guys but there's no heart in it, does that mean my quest cant be finished? I need to start a new character to do 100% of the game?

Comment: Not sure why this is duplicate.  The quest was fixed in 1.4.

Comment: @Iszi, it's the same question about the same quest - if the answers on that question are out of date or need updating, then that should happen.  Duplicating the question doesn't help.

Comment: @agent86 It's not the same quest anymore, now that it's been fixed.  The answers before were perfectly fine and correct for their time.  However, with the new patch, different solutions may be needed for someone having similar problems with the quest.